# Python multiprocess/multithreading use for concurrent file copy operation

Tags: python, multithreading

I am writing python code to copy bunch of big files/folders from one location to other location on desktop (no network, everything is local). I am using shutil module for that.

But the problem is it takes more time so I want to speed up this copy process. I tried using threading and multiprocessing modules. But to my surprise both are taking more time than sequential code.

One more observation is - the time required increases with increase in number of processes for same number of folders. What I mean is suppose I have following directory structure

```
                       /a/a1, /a/a2, /b/b1 and /b/b2
```

If I create 2 processes to copy folders a and b the time taken is suppose 2 minutes.
Now if I create 4 processes to copy folders a/a1, a/a2, b/b1 and b/b2 it takes around 4 minutes. I tried this only with multiprocessing not sure about threading.

I am not sure what is going. Would any one had similar problem? Are there any best practices which you can share to use multiprocessing/threading in python?

Thanks
Abhijit

Comment: Your problem is likely IO-bound, so more computational parallelization won't help.  As  you've seen, you're probably making the problem worse by now requiring the IO requests to jump back and forth between the various threads/processes.  There are practical limits to how fast you can move data on a computer, especially where disk is involved.

Comment: @Joe That's an answer. Move it to one and you've got my vote.

Comment: In order for multiple processes to speed things up your disk's multiple heads to would have to be able to work independently.  But that's not how they work.

Comment: If I/O really is the reason for this, as I suspect, then you should get different results on different hardware.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is likely IO-bound, so more computational parallelization won't help. As you've seen, you're probably making the problem worse by now requiring the IO requests to jump back and forth between the various threads/processes. There are practical limits to how fast you can move data on a computer, especially where disk is involved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Joe. I am not sure if it is IO-bound problem. But yes you are right there is practical limits to move data on disk for given OS and hardware. I just wanted to make sure that I use it to its limit. I tried sequential copy and parallel copy using OS copy commands and noticed that in both cases it takes same time as python sequential copy.